# how to run two microservices on same network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am facing an issue here:

```
version: '2'

services:
  ms1:
    image: somedtr/someorg/somerepo:v0.1
    mem_limit: 512M
    environment:
     SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker-development-cloud
     JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
    ports:
    - "8900:8900"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - docker_dev_cloud

networks:
  docker_dev_cloud:
   driver: bridge
=======================================
version: '2'

services:
  ms2:
    image: somedtr/someorg/somerepo:v0.1
    mem_limit: 512M
    environment:
     SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker-development-cloud
     JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
    ports:
    - "8900:8900"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - docker_dev_cloud

networks:
  docker_dev_cloud:
   driver: bridge
```

i am trying to run the service on docker_dev_cloud but its not running on that network

when i do docker network ls

```
 ms1_docker_dev_cloud 
   ms2_docker_dev_cloud
```

Any Help Appreciated,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Start by formatting your code properly. There's a button for it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Formatted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### edit:

The OP used 2 different `.yaml` files and 2 different networks were being created maybe because `docker-compose` uses as project name (by default) the name of the directory with the `docker-compose.yaml` file. In the comments it was proposed to use:

```
docker-compose -p project_name up
```

---

#### original answer:

I have changed your `yaml` a little bit in order to make something that works and can be demonstrated.

1. I have used the `alpine` image
2. I have changed one of the two <kbd>8900</kbd> ports to <kbd>8901</kbd> because you can't bind it twice (you can run as many containers as you want making use of their <kbd>8900</kbd> port but your host has only one <kbd>8900</kbd> port).
3. I added `entrypoint: ping msX` in order to show you that they ping each other.

---

docker-compose.yaml (run it with `docker-compose up`):

```
version: '2'

services:
  ms1:
    image: alpine
    mem_limit: 512M
    environment:
     SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker-development-cloud
     JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
    ports:
    - "8900:8900"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - docker_dev_cloud
    entrypoint: ping ms2

  ms2:
    image: alpine
    mem_limit: 512M
    environment:
     SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker-development-cloud
     JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
    ports:
    - "8901:8900"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - docker_dev_cloud
    entrypoint: ping ms1

networks:
  docker_dev_cloud:
   driver: bridge
```

you can see that it works, because ms1 - ms2 actually ping each other.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/docker_compose_tests/test$ docker-compose up
Creating network "test_docker_dev_cloud" with driver "bridge"
Creating test_ms1_1
Creating test_ms2_1
Attaching to test_ms2_1, test_ms1_1
ms2_1  | PING ms1 (172.22.0.3): 56 data bytes
ms2_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
ms1_1  | PING ms2 (172.22.0.2): 56 data bytes
ms1_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
ms2_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.286 ms
ms1_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
ms2_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.129 ms
ms1_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
ms2_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.137 ms
ms1_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
ms2_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.246 ms
ms1_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms
ms2_1  | 64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
```

and the network is also created and can be listed:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/docker_compose_tests/test$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                    DRIVER              SCOPE
c8562a9231c3        bridge                  bridge              local
412040f6cf69        host                    host                local
1cbabce12616        none                    null                local
59de206c1ffa        test_docker_dev_cloud   bridge              local
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case i have two different docker-compose.yml for ms1 and ms2.

Comment: This is why you get 2 different networks starting with `ms1_` and `ms2_`. This might be the name of the folders.

Comment: Still not working. Can you please tell me how that `test` come before the network name. in my case its coming like `ms1_docker_dev_cloud` and `ms2_docker_dev_cloud`

Comment: which folder ??

Comment: Docker-compose uses your folder name as a prefix. At my case I used a folder named `test`. Try to use `docker-compose -p your_projects_name up`

Comment: Okay. . What i did is create one folder and put that compose file inside that folder. I have 19 services so i do it same for other hope it works tooo

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers